# Could someone explain below definition with example?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, definition, numerical-linear-algebra

[image: definition]

Could someone help to explain this definition with a numerical example? I do not understand it. I am new learner to this topic. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For example, in $\mathbb R^2$ let $U$ be the subspace spanned by the vector $\pmatrix{1\cr 2}$.  The orthogonal projection $P_U$ has matrix
$$ \pmatrix{1/5  & 2/5\cr 2/5 & 4/5} $$
We have $$\eqalign{\|P_U e_1\|^2 &= \left\|\pmatrix{1/5\cr 2/5}\right\|^2 =
(1/5)^2 + (2/5)^2 = 1/5 \cr
  \|P_U e_2 \|^2 &= \left\| \pmatrix{2/5 \cr 4/5}\right\|^2 = (2/5)^2 + (4/5)^2 = 4/5 \cr}$$
so $\mu(U) = 8/5$.

Comment: thanks, Prof Robert, sorry again, how to get mu(U)=8/5? n=2, how to determine r?

Comment: $r$ is the dimension of the subspace $U$, which is $1$.

Comment: thanks Prof Robert.